# bindService with aidl return false

Tags: android, android-service, aidl

I would like to provide a service that can be called by other app. Therefore, I have a service and an aidl. But when I try to have a separate application to bind this service (bindService), it just returns me false which means fail. Here is my code.

PS: context is already the ApplicationContext which obtained by calling getApplicationContext()

**Code that try to bind the service**

```
  private static ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            sService = XXXService.Stub.asInterface(service);
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            sService = null;
        }
    };

    private static synchronized XXXService getService(final Context context) {
        if (sService != null) {
            return sService;
        } else {
            intent.setClassName(context.getPackageName(), "com.xxx.someservice");
            if (context.bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)) {
                Log.i(TAG, "can bind");
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "can not bind");
            }
            return sService;
        }
    }
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
    <service android:name="com.xxx.someservice"
        android:process=":main"
        android:exported="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems basically right. I think the issue is that intent.setClassName(context.getPackageName(), "com.xxx.someservice"); should be intent.setClassName("Your.package.name.with.the.service", "com.xxx.someservice"); . context.getPackageName() returns the current package name, so this would work if you were trying to bind in your own package, but your question makes it seem like you are doing it in a separate package.

Answer (score 1):

Using an action name for service worked for me.

E.g:

```
<service
    android:name="..."
    android:process="..." >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="your-unique-action-name" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

And:

```
...
bindService(new Intent("your-unique-action-name"), mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Comment: I honestly think using intents is better, since it is more robust from refactoring. But be careful. Your above code is insecure, because any application can call it. Just make sure it is protected with a permission and better yet signature if you can

Comment: In terms of robustness, your code would break if you ever renamed the class or renamed your package. You would have to remember to keep this in sync. It also could be very difficult to change later, especially if you do not own the other code.

Comment: @Bishnu Could u add more about the security,please? Why action name is more robust than simply class name? – Bear 5 mins ago

Comment: For security, any application can call your service because it is not protected by any permission. Hence, you need to make sure that you are not leaking anything sensitive. Protecting with a permission is better, but users cans still grant other apps the permission. If the app is trusted, you should use signature level permissions and sign your apps with the same key

Comment: But what if I want to expose it to third-party app? I think I can not use signature in this case?

Comment: Btw, could u mind put this into your answer as other may also concern it , thank you

Comment: @Bishnu Thanks. I think I can put my signature into the intent in [`startService()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService(android.content.Intent)), and check it in [`onStartCommand()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int)). Could you show us how to work with permission protection as you mentioned? About action name, I used [`randomUUID()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID()) to generate it.